# TCP server client, client only prints incoming string when server socket is closed

Tags: java, tcp, client

For a school project we need to connect a server to a client and get statistics from the server. We want to print the statistics into the command line in client. The server runs a command, sends the result to the client, and the client prints the result in it's console. But the problem is that the client only start printing the results when the serversocket closes.

We are running the server code on a Ubuntu virtual machine and the client code on my windows laptop. When we run both classes locally they do what we want. But when we run the server side on a virtual machine, the client side waits for the socket to close.

Client code:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.Socket;


public class Client {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, InterruptedException {

        try{
            Socket s = new Socket("localhost", 80);
            s.setTcpNoDelay(true);
            PrintWriter pr = new PrintWriter(s.getOutputStream());
            pr.println("hello");
            pr.flush();

            InputStreamReader in = new InputStreamReader(s.getInputStream());
            BufferedReader bf = new BufferedReader(in);

            String str = bf.readLine();
            System.out.println("server: " + str);

            //todo dit moet in server.java gebeuren. Geen reden om elke keer hetzelfde commando door te sturen: wel extra veiligheidsrisicos
            while (true){
                String resultaat = bf.readLine();
                System.out.println(resultaat);
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            }
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println("can't connect");
        }
    }
}
```

Server code:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Server {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, InterruptedException {

        ServerSocket ss = new ServerSocket(80);
        Socket s = ss.accept();
        s.setTcpNoDelay(true);

        System.out.println("client connected");
        try {
            InputStreamReader in = new InputStreamReader(s.getInputStream());
            BufferedReader bf = new BufferedReader(in);
            String welcome = bf.readLine();
            System.out.println("Client: " + welcome);

            PrintWriter pr = new PrintWriter(s.getOutputStream());
            //grep 'cpu ' /proc/stat | awk '{usage=($2+$4)*100/($2+$4+$5)} END {print usage "%"}' ; uptime -p ; df /dev/sda1
            String cmd = "ping www.google.com";

            pr.println("Welcome client");
            pr.flush();

            //todo commando's in deze class zetten en om de zoveel tijd de resultaten doorsturen. Dus niet meer reageren op commando's
            while (true) {
                ArrayList<String> resultaat = runCommand(cmd);
                for (String str : resultaat
                ) {
                    pr.println(str);
                    pr.flush();
                }
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            }
        }
        catch (InterruptedException e){
            s.close();
        }
    }

    private static ArrayList<String> runCommand(String str) {
        ArrayList<String> resultaten = new ArrayList<>();
        try {
            Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(str);
            BufferedReader ret = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));                   //vertaald bytes naar karakters van het eerste bericht van de client
            String line;                                                                                                //output van bufferedreader

            while ((line = ret.readLine()) != null) {
                String resultaat = ret.readLine();
                System.out.println(resultaat);
                resultaten.add(resultaat);
                System.out.println(ret.readLine());
            }
            System.out.println(resultaten);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            resultaten.add(e.getMessage());
        }
        return resultaten;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you put your result in server in an arraylist, that's why it's never sent to client, try this

```
public class Server {

   public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, InterruptedException {

        ServerSocket ss = new ServerSocket(8000);
        Socket s = ss.accept();
        s.setTcpNoDelay(true);

        System.out.println("client connected");
        try {
            InputStreamReader in = new InputStreamReader(s.getInputStream());
            BufferedReader bf = new BufferedReader(in);
            String welcome = bf.readLine();
            System.out.println("Client: " + welcome);

            PrintWriter pr = new PrintWriter(s.getOutputStream());
            // grep 'cpu ' /proc/stat | awk '{usage=($2+$4)*100/($2+$4+$5)} END {print usage
            // "%"}' ; uptime -p ; df /dev/sda1
            String cmd = "ping www.google.com";

            pr.println("Welcome client");
            pr.flush();

            Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);
            BufferedReader ret = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));
            while (ret.readLine() != null) {
                pr.println(ret.readLine());
                pr.flush();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            s.close();
            ss.close();
        }
    }
}
```